# Iniciar função e executar função novamente ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando a página carrega totalmente ele inicia uma função, gostaria que ao clicar em um botão essa mesma função inicializasse novamente passando um texto como `Query String`. Tenho o código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function initMapplic(title){
        var mapplic = $('#mapplic').mapplic({
            source: '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/plugins/mapplic2/server.php?title='+title,    // Using mall.json file as map data
            sidebar: false,          // Enable sidebar
            developer:true,
            minimap: false,          // Enable minimap
            markers: true,         // Disable markers
            fillcolor: true,       // Disable default fill color
            fullscreen: true,       // Enable fullscreen 
            maxscale: 3             // Setting maxscale to 3
        });
    }

    initMapplic('');

    $("#searchfilters").on('click',function(){

        initMapplic('apertou');

    });


});
```

Ele inicia normalmente, mas quando clico no botão ele parece que não atualiza passando o texto **"apertou"** como eu gostaria.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMapplic("");
});
    
function initMapplic (title) {
  alert(title);
  var mapplic = $('#mapplic').mapplic({
    source: 'assets/plugins/mapplic2/server.php?title='+title,    // Using mall.json file as map data
    sidebar: false,          // Enable sidebar
    developer:true,
    minimap: false,          // Enable minimap
    markers: true,         // Disable markers
    fillcolor: true,       // Disable default fill color
    fullscreen: true,       // Enable fullscreen 
    maxscale: 3             // Setting maxscale to 3
  });
}
Veja se é mais ou menos isso que você precisa.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="initMapplic('apertou');" value="Enviar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Retire a função `initMapplic` do escopo do carregamento da página:

```
function initMapplic(title) {
    // ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initMapplic('');

    $("#searchfilters").on('click', function() {
        initMapplic('apertou');
    });
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ainda continua na mesma coisa do primeiro carregamento.

Comment: Coloque um `alert` em `$("#searchfilters").on('click', function() {` e me confirma se está chamando.

Comment: Sim, executou o alert

Comment: Dá uma olhada: http://jsbin.com/tesulebowo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Se também precisar usar a variável declarada em `var mapplic`, também retire a sua declaração do escopo da função.

Comment: O alert eu coloquei aqui e também funcionou, mas na questão da função `mapplic()` executar novamente parece que ele não executa, não atualiza a div#mapplic